# Trouble understanding concurrency example from ebook

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm having difficulty understanding concurrency from an ebook. My hopes are someone can do a breakdown step by step with me so i can clearly understand whats going on.

Here is the main method:

```
func main(){
  c := make(chan int)
  go printer(c)
  wg.Add(1)

  // Send 10 integers on the channel.
  for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
    c <- i
  }

  close(c)
  wg.Wait()
}
```

And here is the printer method:

```
func printer(ch chan int) {
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("Received %d ", i)
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

Here are my questions:

- Why are we only executing `wg.Add(1)` as one group to wait for instead of `wg.Add(1)` inside the `main method for loop`
- I'm really not understanding channels, period.

I've done some research and no one seems to be able to explain it to me in a simple way.

Any step by step simple explanation as to `sending integers on channel` and `adding to wait groups` would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

sourcecode => https://github.com/goinaction/code/blob/master/chapter1/channels/hellochannels.go

Comment: Yes @ThunderCat and im having trouble understanding from readingh

Comment: A simple full detailed explanation as to whats going on would be great, such as why its 1 channel instead of 10 (integers10) and what exactly `c <-` means

Comment: @jkushner: The code has bugs. That's why it makes no sense. What ebook are you using?

Comment: you should take go tour for channels https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2. Also In your code you are using wait group without any reason. It would be better to use it for multiple go routines to synchronize them or wait for all go routines to be finished before main exist

Comment: @ThunderCat I forgot the wait call see code and also added llnk to sourcecode from ebook

Comment: @jkushner still it is not necessary to use `WaitGroup` for single go routine. If you really wants to wait for all values to be printed you can use channels

Comment: @peterSO just FYI, without the `wg.Wait` the main function exits before the last value is printed by the printer.

Comment: The code is just fine. The wait group count `wg.Add` corresponds to the number of goroutines. Once all the go routines are "done" (they signal by calling `wg.Done`), the main thread blocking on the `wg.Wait` call gets unblocked and the main thread exits. Channels help transfer values from multiple go routines (typically many to one) without requiring additional synchronization. You can take the go Go tour or read concurrency further in that book itself to get a proper understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you deliberately add a blocking point in the main thread, the program will seize execution before the last item is printed by the receiver. 
That is the job that is been done by the `WaitGroup` object and the `WaitGroup.Wait()` call.

With this you are telling the main thread that another operation is concurrently occurring and that you want to wait for it's completion before ending the execution of your program. That will be signaled with the `wg.Done()` statement.

However in this case this is only needed because otherwise the receiver would not be able to receive the last item, before the execution on the main thread concluded.
But for the most part, the channels are also a synchronization abstraction, and they are dictating the flow of the execution of the program.

But first things first, **the reason why the `WaitGroup` is not being added in the loop**, is because you only have a single point in your program which you obligatory want to wait for. A single goroutine, which is composed of a single channel.

Since in the example, we are working with an `Unbuffered` channel, it only allows 1 message at a time to be transmitted through the channel. 
**This means that the for each message the transmitter send, the transmitter will be blocked until such message is retrieved by the receiver and removed from the channel.**

When the transmitter sends the last item , it will close the channel indicating to the receiver that there will not be more messages to be received later on.
The iteration occurring with the `range ch` will terminate after receiving the "10", and the execution of the `goroutine` finally breaks off the loop execution.

**This is what was happening:**

// *Transmitter* sends "1"

// *Transmitter* is now blocked since the channel is `unbuffered`.

// *Receiver* receives *"1"*

// *Receiver* is now blocked until something is transmitted to the channel.

// Transmitter is now unblocked and can transmit again.

// .....

// *Transmitter* sends *"10"*

// *Receiver* received "10"

After this, the go function can finally subtract the counter on the `WaitGroup`, by calling it's static method `Done`, and the counter will reach zero, meaning that the block operation occurring due the `wg.Wait()` will seize to exist, and the main thread can finally reach completion and terminate the program execution.

Key points:

- The `channel` which we are utilizing its a `unbuffered` channel, meaning 1 message at a time. With buffered channels on the other hand, you could have multiple messages at the same time being transmitted, before the receiver actually decides to go get them, and the advantages of the `WaitGroup` could be become a lot more obvious.
- with `<- i`, you are sending something to the `channel`, and with `range ch` you are retrieved such messages. The messages transmitted are of a fixed variable type, in this case integer.

Answer (score -1):

**Editor's note: this first paragraph was in response to the author's *original code*, which has since been edited to have markedly different semantics than the code that was originally presented.**

The code example you've provided is not a particularly good example as far as demonstrating the usage of a `WaitGroup`, because the program is terminated by the end of the main method rather than any co-ordination handled by the `WaitGroup`. You can remove the call to `wg.Done()` and that program will still compile and execute fine.

I'm happy to answer your more general questions, though.

*Why are we only executing wg.Add(1) as one group to wait for instead of wg.Add(1) inside the main method for loop?*

It sounds like you're asking why we don't increment `wg` for each integer in the for loop. This is not really the point of `WaitGroups`. A typical use case would be adding 1 for each goroutine that we're co-ordinating beyond the main goroutine. In this example, there's one other goroutine (the one handling `printer`, so we only add 1 to our `WaitGroup`.

A more *clear* version of your above example would be something like the following:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func printer(ch chan int) {
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("Received %d ", i)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func sender(ch chan int) {
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
    close(ch)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go printer(c)
    go sender(c)
    wg.Add(1)

    fmt.Println("Waiting...")
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Finished")
}
```

In this example, we want to *wait* for the `printer` method to have fully printed off all of its numbers we proceed with the main goroutine. So we tell our main goroutine to `Wait()` until all integers have been printed, at which point we tell the main thread to proceed. Unlike your example, we `close` the channel once we've entered all of our ints into it, which allows the `printer` function to stop blocking on `range` and to go ahead and call `wg.Done` - in your original example, the `printer` never stops blocking on `range` and so never actually calls `wg.Done`

*I'm really not understanding channels, period.*

Hopefully the above example makes things a little more clear? I'm afraid this part of your question is a bit too broad for me to answer.